# Mapping a set to a value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to map a set to another value in JavaScript.  I'm relatively new to JavaScript and haven't been able to find an example.  Basically, below I have a map with sets mapped to a string and I want to be able to get the string using .get() on the map.

```
let types = new Map();
const set1 = new Set([0,1]);
const set2 = new Set([1,2]);

types.set(set1, "a");
types.set(set2, "b");
```

Thank you

Comment: Exactly like that, actually. What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's objects are each unique (this concept is called an "Identity"), and so, you can only `.get()` if you have the same *instance*

```
types.get(set1); // "a", good
types.get(new Set([0,1])); // undefined, bad.
```

There's no way to efficiently retrieve a value if you don't have the same instance as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Set` to a string and use that as the key:

`const mapKey = JSON.stringify(Array.from(set1));`

Comment: There’s no reason to do this. Any object or primitive can be a key in a Map.

Comment: See the other answer for why you have to convert to a string.

Comment: But you don't need to since you have references to both sets. The code in the OP works fine because you can retrieve things from the Map is `types.get(set1)` (hence the comment from the moderator).